# Lex v2 only the content of the messages in the attribute of amazon connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I currently face an issue with my amazon connect and lex v2 stuff. The plan is to invoke the lambda the lambda gives me the message and I can refer back to it with the $.Attributes feature in my Get customer input block.

If I reference messages from my lambda of the lex v2 in amazon connect itself, it gives me the hole array like content, contenttype and so on. I only want and need the content itself because this is the json I need to display to the customer.

{
'sessionId': 'string',
'messages': [
{
'content': 'string',
'contentType': 'CustomPayload'|'ImageResponseCard'|'PlainText'|'SSML',
'imageResponseCard': {
'title': 'string',
'subtitle': 'string',
'imageUrl': 'string',
'buttons': [
{
'text': 'string',
'value': 'string'
},
]
}
},
]
}

Here is the link to the docs: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lexv2-runtime.html

Is there anything from the amazon connect side which I can use to only display the content of the messages attribute?

Thanks :)